# MergeAdapter - can't retrieve section position

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I am looking to integrate MergeAdapter into my project and I am having an issue trying to retrieve which section the user has clicked. I want to set it up so when user clicks any item in any section, the section number is returned so I know which section the user is in. The app I am working on requires this.

Code below sets up 3 sections with some data in each section.

```
public class SectionTesting extends Activity
{

    ListView listView;
    private MergeAdapter mergeAdapter = null;

    private static final String[] items =
    { "One", "Two", "Three" };

    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mergelayout);

        context = this;

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mergeListView);

        mergeAdapter = new MergeAdapter();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>(
                        Arrays.asList(items)));

        TextView sectionHeader = new TextView(this);
        sectionHeader.setText("Section One");

        mergeAdapter.addView(sectionHeader);
        mergeAdapter.addAdapter(adapter);

        TextView sectionHeaderTwo = new TextView(this);
        sectionHeaderTwo.setText("Section Two");

        mergeAdapter.addView(sectionHeaderTwo);
        mergeAdapter.addAdapter(adapter);

        TextView sectionHeaderThree = new TextView(this);
        sectionHeaderThree.setText("Section Three");

        mergeAdapter.addView(sectionHeaderThree);
        mergeAdapter.addAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setAdapter(mergeAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                    long arg3)
            {
                Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "You clicked Section "
                                + mergeAdapter.getSectionForPosition(position),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });
    }

}
```

I was hoping getSectionForPosition method would return the value I require, but it just returns 0 everytime. I tried calling the method getSections().length as well to check it was returning the correct number of sections, but again it comes back as 0 everytime.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Edit

I managed to come up with this messy solution. In the MergeAdapter class, under the addView method, I added this line of code

```
view.setId(1000);
```

Then I added this method here

```
public int getSectionNumber(int position)
    {
        int section = 0;

        for (ListAdapter piece : getPieces())
        {
            int size = piece.getCount();

            if (position < size)
            {
                return section-=1;
            }

            position -= size;

            if(size == 1)
            {
                if(piece.getItem(0) instanceof TextView)
                {
                    TextView tv = (TextView) piece.getItem(0);
                    if(tv.getId() == 1000)
                    {
                        section++;  
                    }
                }       
            }
        }

        return (-1);
    }
```

The code seems to work fine, its just a bit sloppy I think. If anyone can come up with a cleaner solution that would be much appreciated, if not, then I will just add this as the answer when I can and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two problems:

1. In order to use `getSectionForPosition()`, your `Adapter` has to implement the `SectionIndexer` interface. `ArrayAdapter<>` does not. All `MergeAdapter` does is try to use any `SectionIndexer` implementations passed to it, and you have passed zero such implementations.
2. You are trying to reuse the same `Adapter` instance several times inside of the `MergeAdapter`, and I have no idea if that will work and certainly do not recommend it.

To address these, create individual adapters per section, and have those adapters implement `SectionIndexer`.

Comment: I was re-using the adapter as I wanted to set-up a quick example to give you an idea of what I was trying to do, in my app I do not do this. I had not used SectionIndexer, I didn't realize I had to implement it in my custom adapter. I have now implemented SectionIndexer and it is working as expected. Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: @CommonsWare, I am struggling while trying to find the adapter instance from onitemclicked event of mergeadapter listview,  
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
   long id) {

  if(mergeadapter.getItem(position) instanceof FeedMentionQuestionAdapter){
   LivLog.info(getClass(), "feed mention question adapter clicked ");
   
  }else if(mergeadapter.getItem(position) instanceof FeedQuestionCursorAdapter){
   LivLog.info(getClass(), "feed question adapter clicked.");
  }